# TypeError: c.match is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting **TypeError: c.match is not a function** in the browser search console when I am trying this code.
where I am making mistake?

```
(function() {
    function addIcon(el, entity) {
        var html = el.innerHTML;
        el.innerHTML = '<span style="font-family: \'B3-Line-Icons\'">' + entity + '</span>' + html;
    }
    var icons = {
        'b3icon-scale': '&#xe900;',
        'b3icon-file-text': '&#xe901;',
        'b3icon-skyscraper': '&#xe902;',
        'b3icon-girl': '&#xea67;',
        '0': 0
        },
        els = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
        i, c, el;
    for (i = 0; ; i += 1) {
        el = els[i];
        if(!el) {
            break;
        }
        c = el.className;
        c = c.match(/b3icon-[^\s'"]+/);
        if (c && icons[c[0]]) {
            addIcon(el, icons[c[0]]);
        }
    }
}());
```

Comment: Can add your code snippet and share it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you make your query against the dom easier. Till now you seem to want all the elements, but why not just query the ones where the className begins with `b3icon`?

So change

```
document.getElementsByTagName(*)
```

to

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class^="b3icon]')
```

After which the logic for the for loop becomes a lot easier

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="b3icon"]');
for (let element of elements) {
  const [match] = element.className.match(/b3icon-[^\s'"]+/);
  if (match && icons[match]) {
    addIcon(element, icons[match]);
  }
}
```

And you can see a sample in this code snippet

```js
(function() {
  function addIcon(el, entity) {
    var html = el.innerHTML;
    el.innerHTML = '<span style="font-family: \'B3-Line-Icons\'">' + entity + '</span>' + html;
  }
  const icons = {
    'b3icon-scale': '&#xe900;',
    'b3icon-file-text': '&#xe901;',
    'b3icon-skyscraper': '&#xe902;',
    'b3icon-girl': '&#xea67;',
    '0': 0
  };
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="b3icon"]');
  for (let element of elements) {
    const [match] = element.className.match(/b3icon-[^\s'"]+/);
    if (match && icons[match]) {
      addIcon(element, icons[match]);
    }
  }
}());
```

```html
<span>Not so important</span>
<span class="b3icon-girl"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

el.className is probably undefined (or not a string).

Answer (score 0):

Check for the value of `el.className`

Check if the value in c is String.